# Не работает GetChild после Destroy в том же фрейме

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему данный код не работает?

1. `MainMenu` это пустой объект для группировки элементов меню.
2. `cl_menu` - переменная, доступ к которой не удается получить.

   ```
   Destroy(mainMenu.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject); // Очищаем 
   Transform tem = Instantiate(mMenu); // Создаем
   tem.transform.SetParent(mainMenu.transform); // Добавляем новый объект
   cl_menu = mainMenu.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject; // Не работает
   ```

Если убрать первую строчку, всё работает прекрасно. Почему код выполняется не последовательно, а асинхронно?

Comment: Если у `mainMenu.transform` только один дочерний объект, то Ваш код очень странный. Его можно упростить: `cl_menu = tem.gameObject`

Answer (score 1):

[`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) срабатывает в конце фрейма:

> Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but will always be done before rendering.

[`DestroyImmediate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html) сразу.

Хотите уничтожить, создать новый объект и сразу его использовать, попробуйте `DestroyImmediate`. Ну, или дождитесь окончания фрейма.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, код правда странный, переделал по-другому - все заработало

Comment: Правда в той же документации, написано, что DestroyImmediate следует использовать только в редакторе

Answer (score 0):

Через корутины с задержкой 0.1f заработало, но это костыль

Comment: Достаточно подождать один кадр.